# How can I request API with Nginx, Vuejs in Public EC2 and Django in Private EC2

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, vue.js, nginx

I have a question about infra setting with Nginx, Vuejs, Django.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NAG2.png)
This is Architecture.

- Nginx, Vuejs's dist/ in WS
- Django(Docker Container), Postgresql in Django Server

and This is Nginx conf.d/default.conf
That's all about Nginx configuration in default.conf.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html;
    }
}
```

And When I click button in UI, I expect the request to go to the Django server.

```
axios.get(process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_API + 'app/test-action/',
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8-sig'
                    },
                }
            ).then(res => {
                var vm = this;

                console.log('ACCESS SUCCESS!!');
                console.log('ACCESS RESPONSE::', res, typeof (res));

                vm.message = res.data.message;
            })
                .catch(function () {
                    console.log('ACCESS FAILURE!!');
                });
```

but, Nothing happened!
I can get `(failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` response in Web Browser.

how can I fix it?

curl worked in Django Server.
like `curl [django_server_ip]:8000/app/test-action/?format=json`

also
curl worked in WS.
like `curl [django_server_ip]:8000/app/test-action/?format=json`

I was able to get a response from server 2 above.

Answer (score 0):

The architecture doesn't to be showing any Security Group rules.

In order for this to work

1. You need a Security group rule to allow all IP4 - HTTP (port 80) from Anywhere to the web server.
2. Another rule to allow connectivity from the web server to the Django server in the private subnet on port 8000 (Source being the SG from Rule 1).

> Security groups are stateful—if you send a request from your instance, the response traffic for that request is allowed to flow in regardless of inbound security group rules.